# How do you left join using "date between" operator in linq?

Tags: .net, sql, linq

I have two tables. The parent table has a single date column, and child table has 2 date columns (From / To). I need to make a left join from parent to child where parent's date column is between one in child. In sql this would look something like this:

```
select p.cob, count(*) from parent p
left join child c on p.cob between c.effective and c.expiry
group by p.cob
```

How does one write this in linq - I'm a bit stuck here....

Comment: This query would be VERY bad.

Comment: @BrianHoover - Why would this be `VERY bad`?  It's a normal structure for time varying relationships.

Comment: @Dems because it would give a Cartesian join between the child and the parent.

Comment: @BrianHoover - Only a partial cartesian product.  What if the range of p.cob extends over years, but the average span of c.effective and c.expiry are in weeks or months?  It is also the only way to check how many child relationship each record in parent has.  Depending on the data it may be intensive, but it's certainly not wrongly formed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be what you are looking for

```
var query = from p in context.Parent
            from c in context.Child.Where(x => p.cob >= x.effective)
                                   .Where(x => p.cob <= x.expiry)
                                   .DefaultIfEmpty()
            group p by p.cob into pg
            select new
            {
              cob = pg.Key,
              count = pg.Count()
            };
```

Comment: This works for what I need, however query performance might be of concern, as profiler is showing a rather big and ugly query sent to SQL server. We'll see how this scales out - these tables will end up being fairly large.

Answer (score 2):

Old but maybe it will be helpfull for others. It made my query 7 times faster on specific amount of test data!

I had (28seconds)

```
from st in subtable
join t in table on st.IdTable equals t.Id
Where t.date >= myStartDate
&& t.date <= myEndDate
&& st == some_other_conditions
select st
```

I changed it to this (4seconds)

```
from st in subtable
join t in table on new { parent = st.IdTable, from = 1, to = 1 } equals new { parent = t.Id, from = (t.date >= myStartDate ? 1 :  0), to = (t.date <= myEndDate ? 1 : 0 )
Where st == some_other_conditions
select st
```

It checks other conditions after creating result of join so all the rest works on smaller amount of data.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question correctly, the *between* part would be handled like this.

```
where p.cob >= c.effective and p.cob <= c.expiry
```

Answer (score -1):

> I need to make a left join from parent to child

There is always more than one way to express a requirement in SQL and I'm sure the same is true of linq e.g.

```
SELECT p.cob, COUNT(*) 
  FROM parent p
 WHERE EXISTS (
               SELECT * 
                 FROM child c 
                WHERE p.cob BETWEEN c.effective AND c.expiry
              )
 GROUP 
    BY p.cob
UNION
SELECT p.cob, 0 
  FROM parent p
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                   SELECT * 
                     FROM child c 
                    WHERE p.cob BETWEEN c.effective AND c.expiry
                  );
```

A good optimizer will spot the repeated derived table, that the two union'd tables are mutually exclusive, etc.