# Left join using between clause linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a query in sql like

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by A.WeekStartDate) as RowNum, 
convert(VARCHAR(12), A.WeekStartDate, 106) + ' - ' + convert(VARCHAR(12), A.WeekEndDate, 106) as Date, 
sum(Data1) as SumData1, sum(Data2) as SumData2, sum(Data3) as SumData3, 
(SUM(Data1) + SUM(Data2)) as OverallSum
from dbo.Weekdays(convert(datetime, @FromDate, 103), convert(datetime, @ToDate, 103)) A
left join TableData T on convert(datetime, T.strDate, 103) between A.WeekStartDate and A.WeekEndDate
group by A.WeekStartDate, A.WeekEndDate
```

It has output like

```
RowNum    Date               SumData1    SumData2    OverallSum
---------------------------------------------------------------
1      02/03/2015-08/03/2015  10            8          18
2      09/03/2015-05/03/2015  16            14         30
```

I am converting this to linq. So far I have tried this

```
from wk in Weekdays
from cr in TableData.Where(x => DateTime.Parse(x.CreatedAt) >= DateTime.Parse(wk.WeekStartDay))
          .Where(x => DateTime.Parse(x.CreatedAt) <= DateTime.Parse(wk.WeekendDay)).DefaultIfEmpty()
          group wk by new { Weekstartday = wk.WeekStartDay, Weekendday = wk.WeekendDay } into wkgrp
          select new { RowNum = ++RNum, Day = wkgrp.Key.Weekstartday + " - " + wkgrp.Key.Weekendday };
```

However, I am unable to access fields of `TableData` in select query to do sum and other operations. I want to left join both tables based upon `TableData.date` between `weekstartdate` and `weekenddate`. How can this be done in Linq?

I referred [How do you left join using "date between" operator in linq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509238/how-do-you-left-join-using-date-between-operator-in-linq) but the answer there uses only count where as I need other aggregate functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query worked for me. In the group statement, I had to change the table name from `group wk` to `group cr` and then I was able to access the fields in the select query.

```
from wk in Weekdays
from cr in TableData
where (DateTime.Parse(wk.WeekStartDay) <= DateTime.Parse(cr.CreatedAt) &&
       DateTime.Parse(wk.WeekendDay) >= DateTime.Parse(cr.CreatedAt))
group cr by new { Weekstartday = wk.WeekStartDay, Weekendday = wk.WeekendDay } into wkgrp
orderby DateTime.Parse(wkgrp.Key.Weekstartday) ascending
select new { RowNum = ++RNum, Day = wkgrp.Key.Weekstartday + " - " + wkgrp.Key.Weekendday, 
       OverallSum = wkgrp.Sum(p => p.Data1) + wkgrp.Sum(p => p.Data2), SumData1 = wkgrp.Sum(p => p.Data1), 
       SumData2 = wkgrp.Sum(p => p.Data2), SumData3 = wkgrp.Sum(p => p.Data3) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following query:

```
from wk in Weekdays
from cr in TableData.Where(x => DateTime.Parse(x.CreatedAt) >= DateTime.Parse(wk.WeekStartDay))
          .Where(x => DateTime.Parse(x.CreatedAt) <= DateTime.Parse(wk.WeekendDay)).DefaultIfEmpty()
          group wk by new { Weekstartday = wk.WeekStartDay, Weekendday = wk.WeekendDay } into wkgrp
          select new { RowNum = ++RNum, Day = wkgrp.Key.Weekstartday + " - " + wkgrp.Key.Weekendday, 
SumData1 = wkgrp.sum(x => x.Data1),
SumData2 = wkgrp.sum(x => x.Data2),
SumData3 = wkgrp.sum(x => x.Data3),
OverallSum = wkgrp.sum(x => x.Data1) + wkgrp.sum(x => x.Data1)
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately mate, I had tried this one before, but that doesn't shows up fields in `x.`