# Linq / Entity Framework - how to group by date with range

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a table of "Cases" with the following data:

```
ID |  OpenDate  |  CloseDate
-----------------------------
1  | 2015-01-01 | 2015-01-02
2  | 2015-01-02 | 2015-01-03
3  | 2015-01-03 | 2015-01-03
```

I want to create a linq query for a specified date range to see a count of cases that are open for each date in the specified range so that I can create a timeline graph of open cases. A case is considered open on its OpenDate, its CloseDate and all dates in between. For example if a case opened Jan 1 and closed Jan 3 it would be counted in Jan 1, 2 and 3.

Here is an example of the results I'd like to get out of the query if the date range I'm querying is 2015-01-01 to 2015-01-04.

```
Date       |  Count
--------------------
2015-01-01 | 1
2015-01-02 | 2
2015-01-03 | 2
2015-01-04 | 0
```

I can't seem to find an easy way to do this without doing a linq query for each date within the date range of the report (e.g. a range of 60 days would then require 60 queries to the database). Is there a simple solution using EF to get these results from one query?

**Edit**
Fixed a count typo. Also as clarification a case is considered open until the end of the close date. For example ID 2 should count on January 2nd and 3rd.

Comment: Your expected result doesn't make much sense. How's `2015-01-02` count `2` and for `2015-01-03` it's `1`?

Comment: `I can't seem to find an easy way to do this` We would also like to see the hard way.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek The OP is looking to answer this question -- for a given date, how many ranges in the first table contain that record?

Comment: @ZevSpitz Yes that's what I'm after - how many cases are considered open for each date within a range. So for example if a case had an open date of Jan 1 and a close date of Jan 3, it would add to the count of Jan 1, 2 and 3. I could theoretically do a loop of each date within the requested range, but I'm hoping to bring it down to one query to avoid multiple calls to the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps try this. First generate the local sequence of dates you are interested in:

```
var startDate = new DateTime(2015,1,1);
var dates = Enumerable.Range(0,300).Select(offset => startDate.AddDays(offset));
```

Then, try this (where `dcx` is your data context and `CaseRanges` corresponds to your first table):

```
var query = from dte in dates
            from row in dcx.CaseRanges
            where dte >= row.OpenDate && dte <= row.CloseDate
            group dte by dte into grp
            select new {Date=grp.Key, Count=grp.Count()};
```

Comment: This worked! Just had to change it to `var dates = Enumerable.Range(0, 4).Select(offset => startDate.AddDays(offset));` and `group dte by dte into grp`

Comment: @BenC3 Fixed. Did you need to use `.AsQueryable`?

Comment: No it ran without it. I'll still have to figure out how to get 0s on dates with no open cases but that shouldn't be too tricky.

Comment: @BenC3 I'm not so sure; it may require a completely different query. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8509506/111794). Keep in mind that there are some performance concerns mentioned in that answer.

Comment: I have run the script twice - once in the way you outlined above, and the other by getting all cases within the date range as an anonymous type from the database with only OpenDate and CloseDate like `.Select(t=>new { t.OpenDate, t.CloseDate }).ToList()`, then using a loop over every date in the range and querying the anonymous types in memory so that there was only one call to the DB. The latter method turned out to be significantly faster and provided the 0 counts we needed, so we ended up using that.

Answer (score -2):

Use a foreach loop and add the start and end dates to a new list so the new list now has 6 items in it and then do a GroupBy on that new list.

Comment: Would be better to show a small snipper of code so the OP has an idea